# Force Rsync Daemon Over SSH

Tags: ssh, rsync

Thanks to the sharp eye of @roaima it has come to my attention that my remote server backup script below, does NOT actually use the SSH encryption as I would like it to.

I based my rsync command on the example found here:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -l ssh-user" rsync-user@host::module /dest
```

However, what is actually happening when my current backup script executes is:

1.) it connects to ssh as the designated user, then
2.) my login notification script confirms the ssh user's login with an email (repeats on disconnect/re-connects),
3.) **PROBLEM**: The rsync daemon connects and does its business **-outside-** the ssh shell, meaning I don't actually get the ssh shell encryption that I want.

I verified this by executing the backup script and then on the remote server executing the `who` command, which confirms that the `ssh-backup-user` is **-not-** connected to the server while the rsync daemon is executing.

My current backup script  (has to executed as non-root user)

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
     rsync -avxP --delete --append --checksum --timeout=180 --bwlimit=150 --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --log-file=/var/log/rsync.log --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.passwd -e "ssh -l backup-user" 111.22.333.444::data /media/user/WebMade/Server-Backups/Prod/today/
    if [ "$?" = "0" ] ; then
        echo "rsync completed normally"
        exit
    else
        echo "Rsync failure. Backing off and retrying..."
        sleep 10
    fi
done
#EOF
```

Might someone be able to clarify whats happening, either I am misunderstanding the man page (most likely :-/ ) or the provided example is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're primary objective is doing backups (instead of having the same files accessible at a second location), you should rather use something like https://www.borgbackup.org/.

Comment: _"I verified this by [...] executing the who command, which confirms that the ssh-backup-user is -not- connected"_ - `who` does **not** confirm that, because it doesn't list non-interactive SSH sessions such as those used by rsync. Even if rsync were transfering data over SSH, you would not see it in that way. `who` is not the appropriate tool to check for this. Then how? Good question; at times I've verified this with `top`. rsync transfering with 80MB/s? ssh consuming 60% CPU? Seems to check out.

Comment: @marcelm  I get the scenario, someone else incorrectly told me that my correct rsync command script was wrong, then rather than admit their own error everything got exacerbated into this rabbit-hole of opinion and confusion post. Compounded by my own ignorance of the who command.  In any case, thx for your feedback all has been sorted out... 'tis life moving on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Everything is just fine, there's no problem here.**

The other answers here are partially wrong and partially missing the point. What you have done is the correct documented way to spawn and communicate with the rsync daemon through an SSH connection. For those unfamiliar with this mode, I recommend checking out the section of the rsync manual called "[USING RSYNC-DAEMON FEATURES VIA A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTION](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html#USING_RSYNC-DAEMON_FEATURES_VIA_A_REMOTE-SHELL_CONNECTION)".

Setting `--rsh` or `-e` to `ssh` in combination with the double-colon `::` syntax enables this mode. Rsync will then connect to the remote machine using ssh, spawn a daemon there (under the SSH session) and communicate with it through the SSH tunnel. This is a very useful mode because it lets you use daemon-only features together with SSH authentication and encryption.

`who` is not telling you what you think it does. `who` (just as `w` and other alternatives) only lists interactive sessions, the `ssh` session used to launch the rsync daemon is not interactive (doesn't even use a shell at all), so it won't appear here. If you don't just trust rsync to do what it says in the manual, you can use `ps -efH` to see the ssh session and the rsync daemon running on the remote machine, `ss -t` to see there's no TCP connection between the machines apart from the SSH on port 22, or `strace` on the rsync process to see the rsync process communicating with the ssh process.

Comment: Thanks for finally providing an efficient reply that directly answers the question(s) being asked in the original post.  You just saved me hours of time. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of a double colon (`::`) in a source of target path indicates use of the `rsyncd` service. A single colon (`:`) indicates a login (typically) over `ssh`.

Once you do that, the remote path must then either start with `/` or it's relative to the home directory the account would log in to.

For example

```
backup-user@203.0.113.1:docroot
```

Remove `--checksum` and let `rsync` decide when to use one. (The only time it automatically skips a checksum is when the file size and modification time match on both sides.)

Stop using any variation of `--append` as otherwise you *will* end up with data corruption in your backups sooner or later. You will almost certainly have wanted `--partial` here, and that's already included in `-P`.

For a `ssh` login `backup-user` on the remote system [`203.0.113.1`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5737#section-3) that has (say) two directories `logs` and `website`, you would then use a command line like this to backup:

```
 rsync -aivP --delete backup-user@203.0.113.1:website/ /my/local/copy
```

I now understand from [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711053/force-rsync-daemon-over-ssh/711057#comment1346356_711057) that you need to copy files from an `rsyncd` service but you want to transfer them across an `ssh` connection that provides a secure (encrypted) transport. Conveniently the man page for `rsync` actually has this an an example: you set the environment variable `RSYNC_CONNECT_PROG` to define the `ssh` tunnel and then connect to the `rsyncd` service within the command itself:

```
RSYNC_CONNECT_PROG='ssh backup-user@203.0.113.1 nc %H 873' rsync -aivP --delete localhost::data/ /my/local/copy
```

Be careful, though. Neither solution gives you no long-term protection against a corruption such as a web page hijacked for a trojan. You replace your backup with a full copy of live each time, so a mistake on live will propagate to your backup as soon as you run your backup script. Consider [GFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme#Grandfather-father-son) or some other multilevel backup schedule (three different backups, one each for Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday would be a start). A tool such as `rsnapshot` can implement this efficiently as a layer above `rsync`.

Comment: this is a great answer & accurate solution.  However, I absolutely want to use the rsync daemon over ssh rather than the normal rsync because of the resource benefits.  I also have to do this as ssh non-root user, so perhaps I need to play with `/etc/rsyncd.conf`  and backup users `.sshauthorized_keys` settings further and make a new post if necessary.   Overall what I am trying to achieve is to connect with a non-root user, then have either the non-root user or root connect to rsyncd.  Perhaps this is worthy of separate post after some testing.

Comment: I misspoke...  the -delete option did in fact delete a partial file that existed on target not on source, but after a very very very long pause... (large file) it seems that rsync is respecting the --partial flag.... so your advice about removing --checksum and --append is dead on... thanks again

Comment: "_the -delete option did in fact delete a partial file that existed on target not on source_" - The `--delete` option affects the target; the complementary `--remove-source-files` option turns `rsync`'s effective action from "copy" to "move".

Comment: "_I absolutely want to use the rsync daemon over ssh rather than the normal rsync because of the resource benefits_" that doesn't make sense (to me). The daemon is a system service. Rsync over ssh is a service that's invoked on demand. "_I am trying to [...] connect [with ssh] with a non-root user, then have either the non-root user or root connect to rsyncd_" - that's not what I understood from your question. I'll either suggest a duplicate or give you a solution for that

Comment: @Time-Bandit there you go. Access to `rsyncd` via a secure `ssh` channel

Comment: thnx for the efforts.  I previously read that solution on the man page and decided against it because it requires changes to my host (target) and source firewalls, security, etc. (port 873 -must- be used.  I was actually hoping for some clarity as to why my chosen solution, which matches the man page "USING RSYNC-DAEMON FEATURES VIA A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTION"  simply is not working.

Comment: `rsyncd` runs on port 873, so that's the port that needs to be proxied. If your server's `rsyncd` is running on a different port then change the number to match reality. It's accessed from the server itself, so there are no security issues there; and then everything is carried over the encrypted ssh channel back to your client

Comment: Using the `--delete` option in a command for backups will result in disaster next time the drive being backed up fails to mount or goes offline.

Comment: @user10489 absolutely. Please read my last paragraph for suggestions on handling this type of issue

Comment: @user10489 thanks I will adjust accordingly.  You would happen to know why my original rsyncd over ssh isn't working according to docs?  I would rather not open port 873 in my firewalls.

Comment: I think the answer in this comment is correct.  Don't use `::` if you don't want to use port 873.  Test by disabling the rsyncd service on port 873.

Comment: @Time-Bandit don't change your firewall configuration. My solution will work just as is. Please try it! (You can test with `--dry-run` if you don't want to make any changes to the local target)

Comment: You can launch an rsyncd that listens on a port different from 873, and the client can connect to it using the normal `:1234` suffix to the hostname in the URL.  I've done it myself.  There may not be much point in doing that for this question, but I wanted to point out that the rsync protocol on other ports is possible.